# Is IOCTL return value

Tags: c, ioctl

I came across the following code.

```
if((error = ioctl(get_card_fd(card_ref), CARD_SETVERSION, &context)))
{
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Does IOCTL always return '0' on success?
2. How does the following expression evaluate to a positive / TRUE ?

   ```
   (error = ioctl(get_card_fd(card_ref), CARD_SETVERSION, &context))
   ```

How does the above expression evaluate to true for a non-zero return value of ioctl?

Comment: 1) No. Read this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html 2) Evaluates to "true" if `ioctl` returns a value different to 0.

Comment: @AntonH You should post as an answer :)

Comment: @JesusRamos I should, but since it's such a short/quick answer, I think it's a bit of a waste of an answer. I miss out on so much reputation :D

Comment: @AntonH - how does (2) eveluate to "true" if ioctl returns a non-zero value?

Comment: Because in C, 0 is false, everything else is true.

Answer (score 6):

It is up to developer who develops driver which handles this `ioctl` request what value to return on success. Usually, `0` means everything went right. This convention has been used in UNIX systems for a long time.

Anyway, read your documentation regarding this particular file descriptor and know what values particular system calls that are handled by this file descriptor return.

As for the second question, the `=` operator returns a new value of variable after assignment. So, the return value (which in our case is `int` for `ioctl`) of the expression is evaluated **implicitly** to `true` if non-zero value is returned by the assignment operator.

Most ways, non-zero **negative** values mean faulty execution. In some cases, UNIX system calls return positive values as the `read` or `write` system calls do. In case of `read` and `write` system calls their positive return value means the number of bytes that were read or written.

It is possible to have `ioctl` return positive value that may mean that execution went normally and we return some *state* of whatever this particular file descriptor stands for. Once again, read your documentation carefully.

So, in the code below:

```
if (error = ioctl(get_card_fd(card_ref), CARD_SETVERSION, &context)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

non-zero value is evaluated to `true` and we enter that conditional block of code.